# How to group components in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Currently, in my vue router, I have many routes looks like this:

```
    {
      path: '/somepath',
      name: 'SomeName',
      components:{
        componentA: componentA,   
        componentB: componentB,   
        body: Body1,  
        componentC: componentC,  
        componentD: componentD
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/somepath2',
      name: 'SomeName2',
      components:{
        componentA: componentA,   
        componentB: componentB,   
        body: Body2,  
        componentC: componentC,  
        componentD: componentD
      },
    },
```

In my App.vue, I have this

```
    <router-view name="componentA"></router-view>
    <router-view name="componentB"></router-view>
    <router-view name="body"/>
    <router-view name="componentC"></router-view>
    <router-view name="componentD"></router-view>
```

There are many duplications because almost every path contains component A,B,C,D. It's even worse when I use nested routes and the children also have A,B,C and D.

Other paths only contain A and D.

Is it need improvment? If yes then is there any better way to work around this or any method to group components so I only need to call it once?? Thank.

Edit: I tried @David's answer. The method `makeRoute` worked if I do this:

```
const makeRoute = ({ path, name, pcbody, spbody }) => ({
  path,
  name,
  components: {
    componentA: componentA,
    componentB: componentB,
    pcbody,
    componentC: componentC,
    componentD: componentD,
  },
});
```

but the `commonComponents` part didn't work. `App.vue` seems does not know what component goes with what router-view and those components didn't show on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refactor your example like this:

```js
const commonComponents = {
  componentA,
  componentB,
  componentC,
  componentD,
};

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/path1',
    name: 'Path1',
    components: { ...commonComponents, body: Body1 },
  },
  {
    path: '/path2',
    name: 'Path2',
    components: { ...commonComponents, body: Body2 },
  },
];
```

If you found that most/all of your routes had the same pattern, you could imagine refactoring this even more:

```js
const commonComponents = {
  componentA,
  componentB,
  componentC,
  componentD,
};

const makeRoute = ({ path, name, body }) => ({
  path,
  name,
  components: { ...commonComponents, body },
});

const routes = [
  makeRoute({ path: '/path1', name: 'Path1', body: Body1 }),
  makeRoute({ path: '/path2', name: 'Path2', body: Body2 }),
];
```

Comment: I edited my question. Could you please recheck your answer? Because it does not work in my case.

Comment: @HùngNguyễn How didn't it work, sir? What error thrown? I don't know what you mean by *does not know what component goes with what `router-view`*. Btw did your code work with your own verbose version and only want to refactor it, or your code hasn't worked too. All @David do was just refactoring from your code.

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh I edited the question. I mean `commonComponents` part does not work well with router-view

Comment: @HùngNguyễn Did you import `componentA`,BCD into the same file as `commonComponents`?

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh I imported all of them in router. Isn't it what David means?

Comment: @HùngNguyễn I don't know, the problem you encountered might be a tricky one because in the manner of plain javascript, the code you put should work the same as David's. Maybe the bug is something that tiny and silly, try relaxing yourself and come back later :))